# angular2 imports via webpack are very big

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using a standard seeded project for angular2 + webpack, and I noticed the `vendor.js` file is **huge**, like 10mb huge. The issue is mainly all of the angular imports:

```
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
```

Is there anyway to reduce the size of these imports?

Comment: Are you using webpack2? It's in beta but provides tree shaking which is how the majority of the gains in terms of package size occurs. **Namely** for production you ditch using a `vendor.js` and just have it build the dependency graph from your entry point and go from there.

Comment: @silentsod do you have any resources on that? I'm using webpack2, but I'm still building a `vendor.js` in production. This is the project seed's webpack config [link](https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Comment: I don't have the resources I used to cobble my webpack (enough to where I could get it to errors I could resolve myself), but I can tell you the primary difference between my dev config and prod config (I have a common base that I use `webpack-merge` on) is that dev specifies an additional entry point. Really, just try removing the vendor entry point. The dependency graph should still be constructed correctly and it should automagically shake things out.